# kotlin variance works strangely in generic function

Tags: kotlin, generics

Here is the code

```
fun main() {
    val sr = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3)
    val des = mutableListOf<Number>()
    copyData(sr, des)
    des.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

```
// A:
fun <T> copyData(source: MutableList<out T>,
                 destination: MutableList< T>) {
    for (item in source) {
        destination.add(item)
    }
}
```

In the above code, `MutableList<out T>` makes `MutableList` covariant. OK, I understand this. But if I change the function signature and have this:

```
// B:
fun <T> copyData(source: MutableList<T>,
                 destination: MutableList<in T>) {
    for (item in source) {
        destination.add(item)
    }
}
```

`destination: MutableList<in T>` makes `MutableList` contravariant on T. OK, I understand. But what I cannot understand is how we can return `item` from `source` now that `source` is not allowed to produce any `item`. Regardless, the code works fine.
I reckon that by

1. Putting `in` in the last parameter, we leave the `T` in the first parameter unaffected.
2. Putting a variance modifier in the first parameter, all the following parameters are affected.

I would appreciate it if you could shed some light on this.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. In both versions of your function the source list is a T producer because it is either invariant or covariant. Your point number 2 is incorrect.

Comment: We don't necessarily need `out` to produce. By default we can both produce and consume. `out` means we can **only** produce, we can't consume. Similarly, `in` means we can't produce.

Comment: In A) I have `source: MutableList< out T>`, does this explicitly mean  `destination: MutableList< out T>`, too? or does `destination` still remain invariant?

Comment: Destination remains invariant.

Comment: If it is invariant, AFAIK `destination` will only take `Number` but `item` is an `Int`, why does the code work?

Comment: Because in this case `T` is `Number`, not `Int`. Source is covariant, it is a producer of `Int`, so we can use it as a producer of `Number` as well. It works like this: `copyData<Number>(source as MutableList<Number>, destination)` where casting is safe and implicit, because `source` is covariant.

Comment: So in B) by the same token, `source ` is invariant, `destination` is contravariant. What type is `T` now? Is it `Int`?

Comment: Yes, it is `Int`. It can't be any different, because `source` is invariant, so it only accepts exact `T`. Then destination is a consumer of `Number`, so it can be used as a consumer of `Int`.